# css background-image won't display in XAMPP for Mac OSX

Tags: html, css, background-image

For some strange reason, everything on my site is working but the background-image for my `div.hero` will not display. Here's my HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section>
        <div class="hero">
          <h1>My Awesome Site</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS

```
html, body, main, section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/baby-room.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Lastly, my file structure found in `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/`:

```
root/
  index.php
  assets/
    css/
      all.css
    img/
      baby-room.jpg
      favicon.png
  header.php
  footer.php
```

Here's the real nutty part. If I just add `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` in front my `url(../img/baby-room.jpg)` I get a half transparent black background, as I should. This really makes me think it's a path issue. The path looks solid, but when I open the path in a separate window I get an `403 Access Forbidden` screen.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's happening. At first I thought it was XAMPP issues but then I uploaded it live and it still didn't work. I've tried single quotes and double quotes, different browser, to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried viewing elements using element inspector and opening the image from there?

Comment: Yes. Just now. We're on to something here.

"You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

In my research I did run into a thread that mentioned they fixed their problem and the solution "had to do with permissions". They left it at that and didn't mention exactly HOW they solved the problem. And I'm too much of a n00b to know what the heck to do here.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: can you test a different image? or a test an absolute url like [http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/](http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/)

Comment: I have tried using exactly your code with just the image changed [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt3dw9np/) its working fine. try set width and height both 100% and check your image name and extension is correct

Comment: Who manages the permissions on your server...if it's not you..talk to them. If it is you, you have to permissions to turn on.

Comment: @g3mini I'm Developing on OSX for a Linux server, which has been giving me plenty of problems, but I've never run into this before.

Comment: @afelixj I did try testing the same image in absolute and it did not work. Using your link does work, but I suspect that just solidifies the permission issues.

Comment: @Tharaka they're divs. They're all 100% width already. Which is why my half transparent black background works.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm a one stop shop... so I guess that means I run the permissions. But I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Well that's a whole other question...perhaps for [**SuperUserStackExchange**](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Try setting the permissions to read & write for everyone, if that works you can work your way down from there.

Comment: Enormous @g3mini. I'd vote you up if I could. Thanks a ton. Solved! Now just to leave this as an answer so other n00bs like me will know what to do with themselves.

Comment: Can't topic got closed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the root folder is contained inside the XAMPP folder, the XAMPP user needs to have access to the files on the computer. The XAMPP default user is `daemon`. If you're getting that 403 Access Forbidden message it's because `daemon` doesn't have access to the files. Change the XAMPP user to your computer's admin user by opening `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` in your text editor of choice. Find the block that says

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

And change it to:

```
User yourUserNameHere
Group daemon
```

Where yourUserNameHere is actually your username used when you do things like uninstall applications and such. It's usually found on the left side of your finder window with a home icon next to it.

Then save, restart XAMPP, then reload the page. Background images should now load with no problem.